# Problem Installing .ttf with FontConfig, in userdir for user account, running RHEL

Tags: linux, rhel, fonts, ttf

I'm trying to install TTF fonts, for a normal user account, on my RHEL5.4 box

The steps I followed are :

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir .fonts
$ cd .fonts
$ wget -q http://www.gringod.com/wp-upload/software/Fonts/Monaco_Linux.ttf
$ mkfontscale
$ mkfontdir
$ fc-cache -fv ~/.fonts
```

fc-list command shows that Monaco is installed

```
$ fc-list | grep Monaco 
Monaco:style=Regular,Standard,Testo normale,Normaal,Normal,Común,Almindelig,Vanlig tekst,Normaali,\u30ec\u30ae\u30e5\u30e9\u30fc
```

But when I try to change font in console, Monaco is not listed.

Comment: Console? Did you mean "terminal emulator"?

Comment: Yes, bash/zsh shell

Comment: Shells don't use fonts.

Comment: Probably because Monaco is not a mono font.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to tell X: `xset fp rehash` will reload the font database.

Comment: Already tried that, still not working